# Selenium C# Элементы с одинаковыми классами

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Я уже задавал сюда этот вопрос, но оказалось, что неправильно составил.
Есть страница. Надо создать бота. Надо кликнуть на определенный элемент, однако у всех элементов одинаковые классы, названий нет. Есть href ссылка. Я по XPath пытался указать путь, но он не видит его. Делал перебор элементов, не нашел то, что его надо. Я новичок, недавно начал изучать Selenium.

Мои попытки:
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@href=""]")).Click();

driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id="body-wrapper"]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/a")).Click();

Эти методы тоже пробовал:

```
driver.FindElement(By.PartialLinkText)
driver.FindElement(By.LinkText)
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector)
driver.FindElement(By.ClassName)
driver.FindElement(By.TagName);
```

И еще много попыток, ничего не получилось. Пробую через браузер Chrome. Мой код:

```
 IWebDriver driver = new OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("");
        driver.FindElement(By.XPath.Click();
        Console.ReadKey();
        driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@href=\"/der\"]"));
```

Выдает во всех вариантах: 'no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[@href=""]"}

Comment: 1. Возьмите HTML код программно, скопируйте его в блокнот и уже по этим данным ищите то, что вы пытаетесь найти, ибо проблема может крыться в том, что сайт еще не подгрузил данные через JS скрипты, но вы пытаетесь найти их. 2. Обращение через индексы (`/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/a`) - это самое ужасное решение, ибо вы гвоздями прибиваете поиск к конкретному месту на странице, а если сайт хоть немного изменится, то все, вы не найдете объект. 3. Даже если объекты имеют "одинаковые классы", они имеют всегда другие различия, например - текст. Пробуйте найти по нему.

Comment: https://devhints.io/xpath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я нашёл решение. Дело в iframe. Надо было найти строчку iframe в source страницы браузера, затем написать код Switch.To().Frame("сюда ид или название фрейма"). Оказывается это из-за фрейма код не может найти путь Xpath. Как я понял, frame не часть страницы, а какая-то служба и сначала надо получить доступ к нему, чтобы дальше все получалось.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]